# Postmates API Integration (Python)

Tags: python, django, api, postmates

I'm using Fareed's Python client for Postmates' API (https://github.com/far33d/py-postmates), but when I integrate it into my site, I get a Server Error (500). I'm using Django and Python, and my site is hosted on an AWS EC2 instance with an Apache2 server. I have a few questions:

- Should the Postmates client be its own app? Or should I just have it
  as a Python file within another existing app (i.e. my cart app)?
- Do the API Key and Customer ID need to be surrounded by <> or ' ' ?
- Even when I try creating its own app or adding it as a file within another existing app, the Server Error (500) is being driven
  by the line 'import postmates as pm.' I have the app listed in my
  settings.py file, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Any tips or pointers would be much appreciated -- especially if you've used this particular API client.

Comment: You don't need to list the app in your settings.py file (in fact, you should remove it). Did you forget to copy the file to your server? If the error is coming at the import line, it means the `postmates.py` file is missing.

Comment: If I include it as a file in my session-based cart app (my project is comprised of roughly 5 apps, 1 of which is a session-based cart) and remove it from settings.py, I still get the error. Are you suggesting that it just needs to be it's own standalone file outside of my project but on my server?